# Insert data into text file python

Tags: python, insert, text-files

I was wondering how do you insert a variable's content into a text file using python?
I'm quite new to this so I would appreciate some help.
Here's my code:

```
a,b = raw_input('Enter in format number^power').split('^')
a = int (a)
b = int (b)
result = a**b
with open("test34.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("result")
print ("Done!")
raw_input()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myText = 'hello python'
with open('myTextFile.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write(myText)
```

This will create a file called `myTextFile.txt` in the same directory as your script and write the string `hello python` to it

Your example has a few mistakes. Here is a working version of it:

```
a,b = raw_input('Enter in format number^power').split('^')
a = int (a)
b = int (b)
result = a**b
with open("test34.txt", "a") as myFile:
    myFile.write(str(result))
print ("Done!")
raw_input()
```

I deleted the quotes from the `myFile.write("result")` line.
Also, you have opened the file in 'append' mode (`open('test34.txt', 'a')`). This means that the program will add your output at the end of the file without deleting what was in the file previously. This might or might not be what you expected. If you would like the program to delete the old file first and then write your output you must open the file in 'write' mode: `open('test34.txt', 'w')`

Comment: Thanks for the help however it fails to work and gives me this error:Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\write to file test.py", line 2 with open ('mytextfile.txt', 'w') as myFile:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Same error with the new code you posted :/.

Comment: Probably cause you're using an old version of python (<2.7). Try the last thing I posted

Comment: Your previous code worked well apart from the 7th line. It says:typeerror: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer not int. I'm using the following code (i just had to import) http://pastebin.com/566BA92L.

Comment: You are right. It did contain an error. But I have modified it now.

Comment: :/. Sorry but i'm very new to this, just began yesterday, now it says Name Error: name 'myfile' is not defined.

Comment: If you just copy-paste the code I've written it should work

Comment: Finally works, final code:http://pastebin.com/tvbkyeiX. Thank you for your help ;).